# Bug in reputation( tab)?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-page

The reputation tab (and possibly reputation itself) might have a bug:

[image]

With 4 accepted answers that would put my theoretical rep. limit at 260, right?

But it seems like it's capped right there for whatever reason. The `/reputation` audit makes more sense:

```
 3   XXXXXXX (-1)
 3   XXXXXXX (-1)
 2   7184180 (10)
 2   7184180 (10)
 3   XXXXXXX (-1)
 2   7184468 (10)
 3   XXXXXXX (-1)
 2   7184468 (10)
 1   7184180 (15)
 2   7184468 (10)
 3   XXXXXXX (-1)
 2   7185059 (10)
 2   7185059 (10)
 2   7185059 (10)
 1   7185059 (15)
 2   7185897 (10)
 2   7185897 (10)
 2   7185897 (10)
 2   7185897 (10)
 2   7185897 (10)
 2   7185897 (10)
 2   7185897 (10)
 2   7185897 (10)
 2   3891901 (10)
 3   XXXXXXX (-1)
 1   7185897 (15)
 3   XXXXXXX (-1)
 2   7191649 (10)
 1   7191649 (15)
 2   7191649 (10)
 2   3792262 (10)  <<<<< this is the answer in question
-- 2011-08-25 rep +253  = 19119
```

Comment: There are cases where the reputation tab doesn't report the correct reputation; this is one of those cases. Only http://stackoverflow.com/reputation always gives the correct reputation.

Comment: @kia But the kicker is the reputation points themselves are affected by this.

Comment: That is also what happens when a question where your answer has been up-voted is deleted; reputation points are affected, and if you check on http://stackoverflow.com/reputation, you will notice that the reputation reported there is lower than the reputation reported on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This used to happen on deleted posts, but will no longer happen (for longer than 5 minutes) as part of [the new reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes).